# collection is not defined in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

When i run the project it says collection is not defined,but when i take collection out of the function,the it works but in this case i cant create routes.Someone please suggest me help......

```
   var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/socialwiki", function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("We are connected");
 }});


exports.getprofile = function (req, res) {
   collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,res, docs) {
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    }else if(res.length){
      console.log(res)
      }
      else{
        console.log('no docs found');
      }
    res.send(res)

  });
}
```

express,

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();
var profile = require('../controller/user');
router.get('/getprofile', cors(), profile.getprofile);
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you post your router Index.js code if exist and app.js code?

Answer (score 1):

> Make sure to exports all the route in your router at last like this:

```
 module.exports=router;
```

**Update**

For getting collection you need to define above like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var collection=require('your collection');
```

Comment: Thank you abdulbarik,the issue is already cleared but it says collection is not found.Can you see my edited code.

Comment: Please define `collection` at top of your file since it's not available. That's why you are getting this error

Comment: When i do that it says cannot find module 'my collection name' it is onsidering my collection as a module

Comment: Yes after requiring it'll become module you need to give correct path of that. And it will work

Comment: sorry abdulbarik i didnt understood can you be more specific

Comment: It's very common mistake I can't figure out if you do not add your folder structure, let's add your collection at top and do let me understand where is your collection exist